# Is Redis AOF file a mix of AOF and RDB?

Tags: redis, persistence

I'm experimenting with Redis and digging into the persistence mechanisms.

If I turn on appendonly (appendonly yes) and turn off RDB (save "") in redis.conf file.

Then I start a new database

And set two keys:

`SET firstKey "I'm first one"`
`SET secondKey "I'm second one"`

I end up with an appendonly file without any headers, only commands:

```
raphaeldelio@Raphaels-MacBook-Pro data % cat appendonly.aof 
*2
$6
SELECT
$1
0
*3
$3
SET
$8
firstKey
$14
I'm number one
*3
$3
SET
$9
secondKey
$14
I'm number two
```

Then, if overwrite the first key with:

`SET firstKey "I'm still number one"`

And then run `BGREWRITEAOF`, the file is rewritten and a header similar to the header of the dump.rdb file is added to it:

```
raphaeldelio@Raphaels-MacBook-Pro data % cat appendonly.aof
REDIS0009?  redis-ver6.2.7?
redis-bits?@?ctimežk?bused-mem˜??
                                 aof-preamble???????֭h
                                                     ????mʗ????~??ױ??firstKeyI'm still number one   secondKeyI'm number two??????֭h
                             ????mʗ??????!4d?%
```

However, I was expecting the file to be rewritten as command logs again.

Therefore I have two questions:

1. After rewriting the AOF file, does it become a mix of AOF and RDB file?
2. How can I decode the content of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to an [AOF file with an RDB preamble](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/4.0/redis.conf#L770-L782). See also [here](https://www.memurai.com/blog/redis-persistence-deep-dive).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following experiment:

1. Stopped Redis Server
2. Renamed `appendonly.aof` to `dump.rdb`
3. Edited `redis.conf`, turned off `appendonly` and turned on `save` again
4. Started the server again

And the server was able to use the `dump.rdb`, which had only the header, to recreate the database.

This makes me believe that:

1. Yes, the AOF file is a mix of AOF and RDB
2. `BGREWRITEAOF` doesn't actually rewrite the AOF file, but takes a snapshot instead